# fopen() in concurrent programming

Tags: c, concurrency, fopen

```
            char aux[20];
            char aux1[20];
            int c;
            FILE* archAuxE;
            FILE* archAuxS;

            sprintf(aux, "%d.txt" ,getpid() );

            archAuxS = fopen( aux, "a");
            if (archAuxS == NULL) {
                printf("this is NOT being printed\n");
            }


            for (j=0; j<nHijos; j++) {

                waitpid(hijosH[0], &estado, 1);
                sprintf(aux1, "%d.txt", hijosH[0]);
                printf("%s---- entrada\n", aux1);

                archAuxE = fopen( aux1, "r");
                if (archAuxE == NULL) {
                    printf("This is being printed :( \n");
                }

                while ( (c = fgetc(archAuxE)) != EOF ) {
                    printf("%c ", c);
                    if (c != '\n') {
                        fprintf(archAuxS, "%c", c);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Hi, this is my code, its a father that waits for its children and concatenates their results using files named after their pid, but I dont know why the archAuxE fopen is returning NULL because I have all those files created. at that time. is that a problem with sprintf or simple a problem of bad handling of the concurrence?.

Comment: What is the `rf` mode? I can't find any documentation of the `f` modifier.

Comment: How the files are created (mode) ? Are you sure that for ANY pid a corresponding file exists ?

Comment: Try checking return values of functions, like `waitpid`... Do not assume a call succeeds.

Comment: waitpid is returning 0 everytime

Comment: thanks to your comments I solved the problem! thank you! the options argument in waitpid had to be 0 not 1

Comment: You might want to have a look at the source code for splitjob at http://splitjob.sourceforge.net/ . Like your program a father process forks a number of child processes and reads their output. However, the child processes do not use temporary files to communicate with the parent. Instead pipes are used to read the output from the child processes.